# Url with data transfer and reading it using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on hosting a website from a shared drive.  While I know that are a lot of options to host a website, but I don't have any admin access to have any software installed for doing this with ease.

http://burnignorance.com/javascript-performance-tips/how-to-fetch-get-request-data-from-url-on-page-load-using-javascript/

The given URL helps me to create a site and pass some value in the URL and then using Java scripting get the information that is passed in the URL.  Now the site that I have created is on the local shared drive and the path is

\server\Test.html

the give path works great.  But is I try to create something like this as per the example it does not work.  can some tell me the right way of creating URL from a shared folder.

\server\Test.html?uid=2&age=24

Comment: You need to set up an actual web server if you have not already. For that, you need admin access

Answer (score 0):

Got it atlast.

When using a shared folder to host a site.  We can use something like this.

file://folder/subfolder/Test.html?uid=2&age=24#